# Android does not create File in one directory, but does in an other

Tags: android, file

I have a small piece of code that just won't write a file to the SD card on Android.

```
InputStream in = thumbnailUrl.openStream();
File outputFile = new File(CACHE_DIR, photo.getId());
if (!outputFile.canWrite()) {
    throw new IOException("Can't write to this file");
}
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(outputFile);
BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream(fos, 1024);

byte[] data = new byte[1024];
int datapart;

while ((datapart = in.read(data, 0, 1024)) >= 0) {
    bos.write(data, 0, datapart);
}

bos.close();
fos.close();
in.close();
```

I made sure I created the folder `CACHE_DIR` before. It exists on the SD card, but `canWrite()` always returns `false`. This is the path: `/mnt/sdcard/Android/data/org.my.app/files/thumbnailcache`

I can browse the directory `/mnt/sdcard/Android/data/org.my.app/files/thumbnailcache`.

**Here comes the interesting part**: When I try to write to `/mnt/sdcard/Test/`, it succeeds.

How is that possible?

Answer (score 3):

do you have the

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

permission?